# F#: weird compiler error when finding an element in a System.Collections.Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, f#, c#-to-f#

I know that there are prettier ways to parse JSON in F# (such as with type providers thanks to FSharp.Data), but for simplicity (as I'm doing this in a fsx file and I don't want to deal with Nuget+Paket paraphernalia yet), I'm using `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` here.

The problem is when I try to find an element in the dictionary, with this funcion:

```
let isTestNet(): bool =
    let json = SomeFuncThatGivesMeAString()
    let jss = new JavaScriptSerializer()
    let dict = jss.DeserializeObject(json) :?> Dictionary<string, obj>
    for entry in dict do
        if (entry.Key.Equals("testnet")) then
            let result = entry.Value :?> bool
            result
    failwith "JSON response didn't include a 'testnet' element? " + json
```

The compiler highlights the second to last line, with this error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    unit     
but here has type
    bool
```

What's the deal? I'm even specifying the type in the function header. Why does it expect a unit?

Comment: The result of your function is `failwith`, you're discarding all previous values. So the compiler points that our for you.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: nope, even with a "false" in place of the `failwith` it fails with same error. @ildjarn is right

Comment: If you put `false` in place of `failwith`, then the result of your function would be always `false`, always discarding all previous values. My comment would still apply.

Comment: if I place `false` instead of `failwith`, the compiler still warns about the same error, so no values would be discarded because the compiler would have not generated anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` expressions are expected to evaluate to type `unit`; having the `for` end with a *non*-`unit` expression does not somehow make it a return value for the enclosing function. Ultimately you need to ditch the `for`.

One option is to use `Seq.tryFind` instead:

```
let isTestNet () : bool =
    let dict =
        let json = (* ... *)
        let jss = JavaScriptSerializer()
        jss.DeserializeObject json :?> Dictionary<string, obj>
    match dict |> Seq.tryFind (fun entry -> entry.Key.Equals "testnet") with
      | Some entry -> entry.Value :?> bool
      | _ -> failwith ("JSON response didn't include a 'testnet' element? " + json)
```

(N.b. due to operator precedence the string concatenation for the error message must be enclosed in parentheses.)

While this reads nicely, `Seq.tryFind` will do an *O(N)* search whereas `Dictionary` itself will do an *O(1)* search when used directly, so if the dictionary is any substantial size this approach isn't viable.

Much more efficient, slightly less obvious (excepting @AntonSchwaighofer's suggested improvement):

```
let isTestNet () : bool =
    let dict =
        let json = (* ... *)
        let jss = JavaScriptSerializer()
        jss.DeserializeObject json :?> Dictionary<string, obj>
    match dict.TryGetValue "testnet" with
      | true, (:? bool as value) -> value
      | true, _ -> failwithf "'testnet' element was not a bool? %s" json
      | _ -> failwithf "JSON response didn't include a 'testnet' element? %s" json
```

Comment: Re: error message: Alternatively, use the often overlooked `failwithf`, like `failwithf "JSON response ... %s" json`